# "an error occurred in the application server (Not found)" message in Android app

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I've been handed a Genexus KB to make an SD app for it. But each time i want to try it i get a "an error occurred in the application server (Not found)" each time i've ran it in a real device (connected in the internal network thorugh) or in an Android Emulator (Andy).

I've setted the KB to point to a local DB stored in my computer and i've tried different ways to try it and it keeps with no luck.

What else should I do?

PS: when i run the web version of it, there's no problem.

Comment: Maybe a firewall setting in your computer? If you access the web version of the KB in the device, does it work?

Comment: Yes, the web version of the KB do work in the device, I can even access to it though the phone's web browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altight people, first of all thanks for the help you gave me!

Secondly @fpanizza that link you gave me was very useful, I could use CatLog with android emulator Andy (after installing Andy Rootkit) and I found out that my app wasn't reaching REST services in the server which leads me to @Franklin, who was right to let me know that it had to do with REST services and I've found out later that i didn't had installed HTTP Activation at one of the WCF Services at the .Net Framework 4.5 Advanced Services, which allowed to reach REST services, and now it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the server URL with the IP of your server.

Is probable that the local host is trying to access itself, the android device.

Service URL property: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?21146

**Update**
I would do what fpanizza suggests on the comment.
 Another troubleshooting idea that may bring some light into problem would be to try to access the rest services from a web navigator on the emulator. The idea would be to validate that the emulator/device can "see" the server. Testing outside the app will help understand if the problem is in the app or the server or the connection device - server.

Comment: I tried that already, and also tried using the IP as server name.

Is there another aspect of the KB's preferences I should put attention to?

Comment: can you try viewing the catlog in the device to see if we get more detail of the problem? : http://tips.genexus.com/2012/07/loggingtroubleshooting-en-android.html . With latest android sdk you can use monitor.bat .

Comment: @JuanEduardoLagos please check my udpate

Comment: Now that I could make CatLog to work in my android emulator, yes, it shows a problem trying to access to REST services in the server.

"Request (GET) to [IP]/rest/LoginSD_Level_detail?Nombre=&Usu_codigo=&gx_id=1&fmt=json"

and

"Could not read remote metadata version from '[IP]/gxmetadata/[file].json' "

Comment: @fpanizza and Franklin check the answer I've just wrote ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Juan.

For better understanding here I enclose the image.

***Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off***

[image]